# What is the source for this sukkah halacha?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What is the source that one must ride an elephant to shabbat evening meals served in a sukkah when the sukkah is to the northwest of your house?

...let's [assume](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-detailed-do-source-seeking-questions-need-to-be#comment8076_2099) that [Double AA is on-topic](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/5323).

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously, you're setting out from somewhere somewhat distant from the *suka* (as you're getting there by elephant). Since you have an elephant, you're presumably in India; somewhere distant to your northwest is thus Israel. Indeed, Israel is known for having many *sukos* on *Sukos*. Who famously brought elephants to Israel? The *Y'vanim* (Seleucids). So by riding to the *Shabas* meal you are reenacting the story of *Chanuka*. On *Sukos*. Thus, you're clearly drunk, so it must be *Purim*. Because you're reenacting the *Chanuka* story on an elephant, you're on the wrong side of the conflict; thus, because it's *Purim*, you're *Haman*. But it says in the *m'gila* "הפיל פור… המן", "the poor elephant was… *Haman*'s". Thus, you ride an elephant.